# IP packet expired by TTL generate an ICMP response in any case?

Tags: ip, tcp, udp, icmp, ttl

Acording to [Wikipedia IPv4 article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#TTL) for TTL header field:

> An eight-bit time to live field limits a datagram's lifetime to
> prevent network failure in the event of a routing loop. It is
> specified in seconds, but time intervals less than 1 second are
> rounded up to 1. In practice, the field is used as a hop count—when
> the datagram arrives at a router, the router decrements the TTL field
> by one. When the TTL field hits zero, the router discards the packet
> and typically sends an ICMP time exceeded message to the sender.

This means that if a TCP or UDP packet expire, the router send an ICMP reporting packet to the origin host?

Comment: That is correct (ICMP type 11)

Comment: "_This means that if a TCP or UDP packet expire_" Packets are IP datagrams. TCP _segments_ and UDP _datagrams_ are the payload of IP _packets_. It is the IP packets that expire, not TCP segments or UDP datagrams.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This means that if a TCP or UDP packet expire, the router send an ICMP reporting packet to the origin host?

No and yes.

TCP segments or UDP datagrams cannot carry a TTL value themselves.

If the TTL on an *IP packet* runs out, the router that expires the packet returns an ICMP *TTL expired in transit* (11/0) to the source IP address.

You can very easily test that by using the `traceroute` / `tracert` utility or by running `ping` with the `-i` (Windows) or `-t` (Linux) option.

For completeness: *no* ICMP *TTL expired* is returned for ICMP packets themselves. The only exception to that exception are *ICMP echo request* packets as used with `ping` with do cause expired messages.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I modified the default ttl:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl
64
```

to:

```
# echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl
1
```

And the packet capture shows that after a TCP packet with TTL 1, there is an ICMP type 11 "Time-to-live exceed" from the router.

So the answer is yes, the router reply with an ICMP to an expire TCP or UDP.

Comment: "_he router reply with an ICMP to an expire TCP or UDP._" The TTL is in the IPv4 packet (Hop Limit for IPv6) header, not for TCP or UDP. TCP and UDP do not have such an expiration, and routers do not look at the IP packet payload (TCP, UDP, etc.), only the IP packet header.